# particle system weird result on some faces

Tags: particles, faces, hair

I 'm trying to use a hair particle system in a plane mesh, but I get a weird appearance. In the image, you can see what is the problem. It seems to act differently in some faces. I have tried to change the Emission->Source->Emit From->Faces to Volume or Verts but nothing happened. This problem disappears when I reduce the amount of total number (Emission or children). In the Children tab when I use Simple instead of Interpolated, this occurs to the hole plane. Except that, the children go outside the mesh in edges.
*I have uploaded the file now.

Thanks in advance.
[image: hair particle system]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the file? only checking your images is quite hard to help you: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: If you want to have hairs only from the mesh you should reduce the "radius" setting from the children > simple.

Comment: I tried to reduce the radius of children, the problem just changes its shape. So, I have reduced the total amount of hair until this problem disappears. But still, I can't understand why this happened.